# Excel Text and Month Function Returning Unexpected Value

Tags: excel

I have an Excel column with dates in it. The first date is 5/1/2020.

I use `MONTH(A1)` and get 5, as expected.

When I wrap it in text, i.e. `TEXT(MONTH(A1),"mmm")`, I get Jan.

This is true of every date in the column.

Why is TEXT not interpreted the month correctly?

Comment: Remove the `MONTH`: `TEXT(A1, "mmm")`. Your current formula is equivalent to calling `TEXT` on the date `1/5/1900`, which is the date that the value `5` corresponds to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "mmm" parameter requires a date value.  By passing it Month(A1), you are passing it the value of 5 which is January 5, 1900 when converted to a date, so it returns Jan.

You need to pass in the full date value (ie A1)

So this will work:
TEXT(A1, "mmm")